# ReactJS fetch then() not recognized

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a project with ReactJS, and am trying to read a local JSON file that I've cooked up.

I have an app.js file which looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

    getData() {
        return fetch('./examples/test.JSON').then(response => {
           return response.json();
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.getData());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

export default App;

The getData function attempts to fetch a JSON file and return the response. However, neither the then() function nor the json() function are recognized.

Is there an import I am missing? I thought they would have come from isomorphic-fetch.

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognized"? You mean not defined? What is your error message?

Answer (score 1):

Reading through [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) docs, you will see a warning at the top of the README:

> You must bring your own ES6 Promise compatible polyfill, I suggest es6-promise.

Try installing and including the polyfill as suggested on their README:

`require('es6-promise').polyfill();`

`require('isomorphic-fetch');`

My guess is that this will make `.then` work.

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting? If you are expecting the `console.log(this.getData())` to output your data, then you are using fetch wrong. The result of `this.getData()` is still a promise, because the result of `response.json()` is also a promise, not the actual data. Modify your code like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //console.log(this.getData());
    this.getData().then(jsonData => {
      console.log(jsonData);
    });
}
```

This is why you see in the [examples for `isomorphic-fetch`](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch#usage) they have a second `.then()` method to consume the result of `response.json()`;

```
fetch('//offline-news-api.herokuapp.com/stories')
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(stories) {
        console.log(stories);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data JSON data from another file then you can directly export that JSON const from that file and import that cont and use it.

Like

Export your json from file

Test.js

```
export default const json = {
A:1, b:2
//......
}
```

In abc.js

```
Import json from "Test.js"

Comsole.log(" a is ", json.A)
// a is 1
```

And i think isomorphic-fetch is used for making api call rather then accessing local file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use axios?

Simply add axios to your project by `npm install --save axios`

And then do this

```
....
import axios from 'axios';
....
async function getData(){
    const res = await axios.get('./examples/test.JSON');
    console.log(res);
    return res;
}

render(){
    return(
      <div>{this.getData()}</div>
    )
}
```